# Subclassed UITextfield - add a member?

Tags: xcode, swift

I am trying to add a member,rowindex, to a subclassed UITextfield:

```
class IngenCursorTextFieldSubClass: UITextField {

var rowindex=0

override func caretRectForPosition(position: UITextPosition!) -> CGRect
{
    return CGRectZero
}
}
```

But I can't use is, not found. All I find is examples in Objective-C which I can't translate into Swift.

I am using storyboard. I am all new to Xcode, Swift....

Comment: Did you make sure that the variable with which you are trying to access it is defined as your custom class?

Comment: How are you trying to access it?

Comment: using the outlet "MyUitextfield"; MyUitextfield.rowindex=0

Comment: Yes, I have selected the customclass for this UITExtfield

Comment: For some unknown reason a restart of Xcode helped to solve this. Now it's working.